# for-in loop to for loop or forEach

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, foreach, for-in-loop

Ok I have the following scenario. I need to convert this for-in loop to either a for loop or forEach. I have tried a few different examples but can't seem to get the code to append to the page. The for-in loop will work however for the code I need to write, it is not allowed.

This is an example variable

```
var work = {
        "jobs": [{

                "employer": "Java",
                "title": "Script",
                "dates": "2017",
                "description": "description",
            }
        }
```

This is the code that I have to work. Currently in a for-in loop but need it into a for or forEach loop.

```
function displayWork() {
    for (job in work.jobs) {
        //create new div for work experience
        $("#workExperience").append(HTMLworkStart);
        //concat employer and title
        var formattedEmployer = HTMLworkEmployer.replace("%data%",
            work.jobs[job].employer);
        var formattedTitle = HTMLworkTitle.replace("%data%", work.jobs[job].title);
        var formattedEmployerTitle = formattedEmployer + formattedTitle;
        $(".work-entry:last").append(formattedEmployerTitle);

        var formattedDates = HTMLworkDates.replace("%data%", work.jobs[job].dates);
        $(".work-entry:last").append(formattedDates);
        var formattedDescription = HTMLworkDescription.replace("%data%",
            work.jobs[job].description);
        $(".work-entry:last").append(formattedDescription);
    });
}

displayWork();
```

Comment: Your sample code is not valid JSON. Are you sure it's correct? Also, please remember to tag the **language** of your questions in future; I've added JavaScript and jQuery tags to this question :)

Comment: Seconding @ObsidianAge -- additionally, I just went through to try to clean up your code blocks and there's also a syntax issue in the JavaScript.  I'd recommend getting a linter for your editor -- it will help you spot simple syntax issues before they become a problem in the browser.

Comment: "*I need to convert this for-in loop […] [It works for me, but] it is not allowed.*" - Why? What doesn't allow it?

Comment: Its for a project I'm working with. The instructors helped build part of the project but I was taught using the for-in way for several examples but didn't give any examples of how do it in a for loop and for the submission, the for-in loop is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you will have an *array* of jobs inside the work *object*, although your example is missing the closing square bracket for the jobs array, and it might be clearer if you had more than one entry in the array.

Given a data structure like this:

```
var work = {
  jobs: [
    {
      employer: "example1"
    },
    {
      employer: "example2"
    },
    {
      employer: "example3"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can use a simple for loop based on the fact that the jobs array will have consecutive integer keys starting at zero:

```
for (var i = 0; i < work.jobs.length; i++) {
  // do stuff with current job in work.jobs[i]
  var current_employer = work.jobs[i].employer;
}
```

Comment: @ChadAndersen -- glad you found a working solution-- please remember to mark your selected answer so that the poster gets credit and visitors to this post are quickly pointed to the solution that worked for you.